# Writing NSTextStorage to file

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am building an app where I need to take the text from a text field and output it to a file. The problem I have encountered in trying to write textStorage to a file because it needs to be a string. The error I receive is "Value of type 'NSTextStorage' has no member 'write'"

I have tried casting to a string on a new line, but have failed in figuring it out.

```
if let textView = TextField.documentView as? NSTextView {
     let result: NSTextStorage = textView.textStorage!

     try! result.write(toFile: "/Desktop", atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}
```

Comment: But the NSTextStorage has a `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the string contents of `NSTextStorage` via the member `string`. That value is a `String` so you need to convert it to a `NSString` to call the write function you are calling.

```
let nsstring = result.string as NSString
try! nsstring.write(toFile: "/Desktop", atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Of course you could use the `String` equivalent `write<Target>(to target: inout Target)` instead.

Comment: You definitely ***don't** need to convert it to a `NSString`*

Comment: Thank you! This was able to fix my problem